If $\varphi(n)=2p$ then $p$ is a Sophie Germain Prime
Define $n,p\in\mathbb{N}$ with p prime. I'm struggling to show that if $\varphi(n)=2p$, then $2p+1$ is prime.

If $n$ is a power of $2$, then so is $\varphi(n)$, so $p=2$ with $2p+1=5$ a prime. So we may assume $n$ is divisible by an odd prime.
If $q$ is an odd prime dividing $n$, then $q-1$ divides $\varphi(n)$. So there exists an integer $k$ such that $2p=2(\frac{q-1}{2})k$, so either $k=1$ and $q=2p+1$, or $q-1=2$, and hence $q=3$.
In the first case, you are done. In the second case, writting $n=3^rm$ with $\gcd(3,m)=1$, we have $2p = 2\times 3^{r-1}\varphi(m)$, so $1\leq r\leq 2$.
If $r=2$, then $p=3$, $n=9$ or $18$, and $2p+1=7$ is prime, and you are done.
If $r=1$, then $\varphi(m) = p$. Since $\varphi(m)$ is odd if and only if it equals $1$, it follows that $p=2$,   and you are done.
